# Jenkins JNLP4-connect connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed after the success of build procedure

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, cd

I got a failure after all the build procedure were finished without any errors.

And I don't know why below error has occurred.

This error has marked the status of a job as a failure even all the tests were successfully finished.
FATAL: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from socautovm1.xxx.local/192.168.114.144:65033 failed
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from socautovm1.xxx.local/192.168.114.144:65033

```
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:1078)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree.get(ProcessTree.java:399)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1090)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1081)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from socautovm1.xxx.local/192.168.114.144:65033 failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:961)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:1078)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the agent is down. Check in which node the job runs and check its status. You may need to restart the node or even free some space in order to get it back online if the current status is offline.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the jenkins agent service and it resolved the issue. (/service/jenkins-agent)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when trying to run a Job on Jenkins that fetches the list of containers on a Slave node.

Whenever I run the job I get the error below:

> ERROR: Issue with creating launcher for agent Linux1(Docker). The agent is being disconnected
> [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
> ERROR: SEVERE ERROR occurs
> org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "unknown": Remote call on Linux1(Docker) failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply restarted the Jenkins service on the main/master node.

**For Windows servers**:

Search for **Services** and then locate the Jenkins service and restart it.

**For Linux servers**:

You might need to use Systemd (`sudo systemctl restart jenkins`).